# Erro ao preencher O datatable PrimeFaces Jsf

Tags: java

Minha Entidade:

```
package Entidades;


public class Aluno {
    private String nome;
    private int idade;

    public String getNome() {
        return nome;
    }

    public void setNome(String nome) {
        this.nome = nome;
    }

    public int getIdade() {
        return idade;
    }

    public void setIdade(int idade) {
        this.idade = idade;
    }


}
```

DAO:

```
package DAO;

import Entidades.Aluno;
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;

public class AlunoDAO {
    private Connection con;

    public AlunoDAO(){
        try {
            con = new Conexao().conectar();
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlunoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        }

    public List<Aluno> Listar(){
        String sql = "SELECT * FROM aluno";
        List<Aluno> alunos = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            PreparedStatement stat = con.prepareStatement(sql);
            ResultSet rs = stat.executeQuery();
            alunos = listar_Aluno(rs);
            stat.close();
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(AlunoDAO.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        return alunos;
    }
     private List<Aluno> listar_Aluno(ResultSet result) throws SQLException{
        List<Aluno> comp = new ArrayList<>();

        while(result.next()){
            Aluno c1 = new Aluno();
            c1.setNome(result.getString("nome"));
            c1.setIdade(result.getInt("idade"));

            comp.add(c1);

        }
                return comp;
    }


}
```

A página Xhtml:

```
    <h:head>
        <title>Facelet Title</title>
    </h:head>
    <h:body>
        <h:form>
            <p:toolbar>
                <p:toolbarGroup>
                    <p:commandButton value="Buscar" action="#{alunoBean.listar}" update="@form"/>
                </p:toolbarGroup>
            </p:toolbar>
            <p:dataTable var="Alu" value="#{alunoBean.alunos}" >
                <p:column headerText="Nome">
                    <h:outputText value="#{Alu.nome}"/>
                </p:column>
                <p:column headerText="Idade">
                    <h:outputText value="#{Alu.idade}"/>

                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
    </h:body>
</html>
```

Quando executo a pagina a tabela não é atualizada, alguém sabe como resolver?

Comment: Leandro, você já debugou seu código para saber se a lista é preenchida a partir da consulta ao banco?

Comment: Posta o manegedbean.